# Postfix: Couldn't Stop "SASL LOGIN authentication failed" Attack in Mail Logs

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, postfix, ufw

I'm trying to stop an attack and logs with `SASL LOGIN authentication failed` for my mail server. However, I've been trying for a day and am still not able to achieve it. The logs continue to generate the attack with the same IP.

## Machine

```sh
Linux server 5.4.0-109-generic #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 8 09:10:54 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## Mail Logs in `/var/log/mail.log`

```sh
Apr 28 20:45:23 server postfix/smtpd[112579]: connect from unknown[5.34.207.81]
Apr 28 20:45:24 server postfix/smtpd[112409]: warning: unknown[5.34.207.81]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Apr 28 20:45:25 server postfix/smtpd[112409]: disconnect from unknown[5.34.207.81] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Apr 28 20:45:30 server postfix/smtpd[112599]: connect from unknown[5.34.207.81]
Apr 28 20:45:31 server postfix/smtpd[112579]: warning: unknown[5.34.207.81]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Apr 28 20:45:32 server postfix/smtpd[112579]: disconnect from unknown[5.34.207.81] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
Apr 28 20:45:36 server postfix/smtpd[112409]: connect from unknown[5.34.207.81]
Apr 28 20:45:38 server postfix/smtpd[112599]: warning: unknown[5.34.207.81]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: authentication failure
Apr 28 20:45:38 server postfix/smtpd[112599]: disconnect from unknown[5.34.207.81] ehlo=1 auth=0/1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=3/4
```

## Fail2Ban with IPtables

#### `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```sh
[postfix-sasl]

enabled  = true
port     = smtp,ssmtp,465,submission,imap,imaps,pop3,pop3s

bantime = 10m
filter   = postfix-sasl
#action   = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,ssmtp,465,submission,imap,imaps,pop3,pop3s", protocol=tcp]
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 15
```

I did `sudo service fail2ban restart` and the wired thing is that I didn't see any chain with `f2b-postfix`.

So did a grep from `fail2ban` logs and here's the output:

#### Fail2Ban Logs in `/var/log/fail2ban.log`

```sh
2022-04-27 16:27:10,133 fail2ban.actions        [567]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Unban 5.34.207.81
2022-04-27 16:27:45,391 fail2ban.actions        [567]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Ban 5.34.207.81
2022-04-27 16:32:17,801 fail2ban.actions        [567]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Unban 212.70.149.72
2022-04-27 22:37:46,299 fail2ban.actions        [567]: NOTICE  [postfix-sasl] Unban 5.34.207.81
```

## Fail2Ban with UFW

In my research, I understand that Fail2Ban can work with UFW so I did some research for it and here's my config:

#### `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```sh
[postfix-sasl]

enabled  = true
journalmatch =
backend = polling
bantime = -1    // Permanent ban? Maybe 
filter   = postfix-sasl
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 15
banaction = ufw
findtime = 120
```

Worth to mention that I've manually input `sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 5.34.207.81 to any` with `sudo ufw reload` but unfortunately I'm still able to see the attack from the same IP at mail logs in `/var/log/mail.log`

```sh
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   DENY        212.70.149.72             
Anywhere                   DENY        5.34.207.81
```

## Filter For Both in Fail2Ban

#### `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/postfix-sasl.conf`

```sh
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
_daemon = postfix/smtpd
failregex = ^(.*)\[<HOST>\]: SASL (?:LOGIN|PLAIN) authentication failed:(.*)$
ignoreregex =
```

Resources: [**Fail2ban with UFW**](https://serverfault.com/questions/1067723/how-to-set-up-fail2ban-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Appreciate it if someone can help me with this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updates

Finally, my `Fail2Ban` works as expected and I'm going to mark this as the answer!

The solution is to set `action` equal to `iptables-multiport` to ban multiple ports! However, I do not use `UFW` to restrict the attacker because I realise `UFW` is always not enabled during the boot due to conflicts with the `firewalld`.

## Solutions

Add this line into your `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`

```sh
action = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,ssmtp,465,submission,imap,imaps,pop3,pop3s"]
```

It should be look something like this:

```sh
[postfix-sasl]

enabled  = true
filter   = postfix-sasl
action   = iptables-multiport[name=postfix, port="smtp,ssmtp,465,submission,imap,imaps,pop3,pop3s"]
logpath  = /var/log/mail.log
maxretry = 15
bantime  = 12h
```

Previously I've set `maxretry` to `3` for testing purposes. You might want to change it to a higher value. Else your user might quickly get into trouble.

## Check Fail2Ban Status

It is worth checking your jail:

```sh
sudo fail2ban-server status postfix-sasl
```

Output:

```sh
Status for the jail: postfix-sasl
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 2
|  |- Total failed:     49
|  `- File list:        /var/log/mail.log
`- Actions
   |- Currently banned: 1
   |- Total banned:     3
   `- Banned IP list:   5.34.207.81
```

Resources: [**Fail2Ban Cannot Set Iptables Rules:**](https://serverfault.com/questions/893504/fail2ban-cannot-set-iptables-rules)

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting that depending on the number of users you have you may want to lower the threshold, and based on the number of attacks maybe increase the ban time.

I don't use Postfix but instead use Exim.However, the challenges of blocking attackers are the same. Here you can see a status of my Fail2ban jail to give you an idea of the botnet sizes out there:

XXXX@XXXX:~# fail2ban-client status exim

Status for the jail: exim
|- Filter
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  |- Total failed:     10380
|  `- File list:        /var/log/exim4/mainlog`   - Actions
|- Currently banned: **1763**
|- Total banned:     **5644**
`- Banned IP list:   XXXXXXXXXXXX